# Thymeleaf 3 and Tiles2 integration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, tiles2

Does Thymeleaf 3 support Tiles 2 somehow? There is a package that I was using for Thumeleaf 2.x.x `thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-spring4` but as I see now it is not compatible because of changes in `org.thymeleaf.dialect.AbstractDialect` class

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.thymeleaf.dialect.AbstractDialect: method <init>()V not found
[INFO]  at org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.dialect.TilesDialect.<init>(TilesDialect.java:46)
```

Do I need to wait for an update of this integration to be able to start with T3?

Is there any way that I can simulate Tiles in Thymeleaf3

I only use my Tiles for something like this:

```
  <definition name="portal/**" template="layouts/portal">
    <put-attribute name="_head" value="/portal/{1} :: _head"/>
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/portal/{1} :: content"/>
  </definition>
```

Comment: any Solutions found?

Comment: I have posted the solution as the accepted answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve that problem I have created a proxy for `SpringTemplateEngine` and advised`TemplateEngine.process()` method.

**How it works:**

The code map layouts on the basis of template path for instance:

```
portal/moje_konto/moje_dane
```

is mapped to layout

```
 LAYOUTS_PATH/portal
```

Additionally, it passes variable VIEW containing a path to actual template

Inside layouts it may be used to include specific fragments. 
Very simple portal layout may look like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html lang="pl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">
    <body>
       <div th:replace="${'portal/' + VIEW} :: content">Content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String home(Model model) {

    return "portal/home/index";
  }
```

**TemplateEngine:**

```
public class LayoutTemplateEngine implements ITemplateEngine, MessageSourceAware, InitializingBean {

  private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

  private final String LAYOUTS_PATH = "layouts/";

  private final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

  @Override
  public void process(TemplateSpec templateSpec, IContext context, Writer writer) {
    String template = templateSpec.getTemplate();

    logger.info("Rendering template: " + template);

    if (context instanceof WebExpressionContext) {
      int end = template.indexOf("/");
      if (end != -1) {
        // change template
        templateSpec = new TemplateSpec(LAYOUTS_PATH + template.substring(0, end), templateSpec.getTemplateSelectors(), templateSpec.getTemplateMode(), templateSpec.getTemplateResolutionAttributes());
        // add VIEW variable
        ((WebExpressionContext)context).setVariable("VIEW", template.substring(end + 1));
      }
    }

    templateEngine.process(templateSpec, context, writer);
    logger.info("Rendering finished");
  }

  public void setTemplateResolver(final ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
  }

  public void setEnableSpringELCompiler(final boolean enableSpringELCompiler) {
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(enableSpringELCompiler);
  }

  public void addDialect(final IDialect dialect) {
    templateEngine.addDialect(dialect);
  }

  public void addTemplateResolver(final ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
  }

  @Override
  public IEngineConfiguration getConfiguration() {
    return templateEngine.getConfiguration();
  }

  @Override
  public String process(String template, IContext context) {
    return process(new TemplateSpec(template, null, null, null), context);
  }

  @Override
  public String process(String template, Set<String> templateSelectors, IContext context) {
    return process(new TemplateSpec(template, templateSelectors, null, null), context);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("resource")
  @Override
  public String process(TemplateSpec templateSpec, IContext context) {
    final Writer stringWriter = new FastStringWriter(100);
    process(templateSpec, context, stringWriter);
    return stringWriter.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public void process(String template, IContext context, Writer writer) {
    process(new TemplateSpec(template, null, null, null), context, writer);
  }

  @Override
  public void process(String template, Set<String> templateSelectors, IContext context, Writer writer) {
    process(new TemplateSpec(template, templateSelectors, null, null), context, writer);
  }

  @Override
  public IThrottledTemplateProcessor processThrottled(String template, IContext context) {
    return processThrottled(new TemplateSpec(template, null, null, null), context);
  }

  @Override
  public IThrottledTemplateProcessor processThrottled(String template, Set<String> templateSelectors, IContext context) {
    return processThrottled(new TemplateSpec(template, templateSelectors, null, null), context);
  }

  @Override
  public IThrottledTemplateProcessor processThrottled(TemplateSpec templateSpec, IContext context) {
    return templateEngine.processThrottled(templateSpec, context);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    templateEngine.afterPropertiesSet();
  }

  @Override
  public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
    templateEngine.setMessageSource(messageSource);
  }
}
```