# generate menu bar in thymeleaf (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is it possible to generate some kind of menu bar in spring boot and display it on all web pages?
So I have a web service where I want to add a menu bar, the menu bar should be flexible, because it is still an in-progress project.

At first, my idea was to work with Java reflection, but that wouldn't work out well since it only shows the method name, which is different than the page name... (like `getClient(...)` which should have a page name of view client. I also have tried the build-in feature to reflect on Spring boot mappings and give them a name, but then you would have the problem that you can't group certain pages.

So my last idea was to manually generate one json and parse it every time a page is loaded, so I could do something like

```
<th:block>
    <li th:each="item : ${json}">
         <a th:href="@{http://domain.com/__${item.link}__}" th:text="${item.name}"/>
    </li>
</th:block>
```

So how could I parse this Json object? withoud making a new class?

thanks in advance,
Jari Van Melckebeke

Comment: I have no idea what you want to achieve. If you would like to add a menu bar on every page you can try thymeleaf layout dialect, apache tiles or if you use thymeleaf3 to write a custom implementation of SpringTemplateEngine like here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322740/thymeleaf-3-and-tiles2-integration/40529148#40529148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking more like a sitemap? Which gives you a page with all the possible URL's for a site.

What I would do is add the `actuator` package to your spring boot project. I would then hit the `mappings` endpoint see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html which will produce your JSON file and then create a list of URLs in your model attributes for Thymeleaf to then render.